# Why is there error in this nonlinear optimization programming? /an entropy maximization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, entropy

I'm trying to maximize the relative entropy, which is nonlinear optimization with linear constraints.

```
seq(1,10)/sum(seq(1,10)
```

is prior discrete probability of 10 events.

```
library(NlcOptim)
    objectfunc <- function(x){sum(x*log(x))-sum(x*log(seq(1,10)/sum(seq(1,10)))}
    poste2 <- solnl(rep(0.1,10),objectfunc,Aeq = matrix(rep(1, 10), nrow=1),Beq = 1,lb=rep(0,10),ub=rep(1,10))
```

It turns out to be

```
Error in if (f < 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In log(x) : NaNs produced
```

However, a little change in object function works

```
library(NlcOptim)
    objectfunc <- function(x){sum(x*log(x))}
    poste2 <- solnl(rep(0.1,10),objectfunc,Aeq = matrix(rep(1, 10), nrow=1),Beq = 1,lb=rep(0,10),ub=rep(1,10))
```

I just can't figure out why there's error. I'd be grateful for any advice!

Comment: You should protect the log(x) against negative x values. Some NLP solvers will allow you to provide bounds that the solver will not exceed. Otherwise, protect the function evaluation yourself (return a large value when x<=0).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! My original lower bound is rep(0,10). I find that rep(0.001,10) works.